# v-autocomplete on-select on-remove in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there any on-select, on-remove properties in v-autocomplete in vuetify? I would like to handle those events manually. I tried @change, but in this case i don't know which one is added/removed.

```
  <v-autocomplete
    :items="states"
    item-text="name"
    label="State"
    @change="pushOrRemoveStates()"
    multiple
  ></v-autocomplete>
```

In the @change, i am calling method **pushOrRemoveStates**. i can select multiple options in autocomplete, so in here i would like to handle onSelect & onRemove of the options, i have to do few operations once we select/remove the options. Its not possible using @change because i don't know weather option is selected or removed, because in both cases @change will execute.

Comment: add some code snippet please

Comment: Hey, i updated the question, please check.

Comment: I need some thing like this in vuetify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427928/material-2-autocomplete-select-option

Comment: Any think like `@select` `@remove` for v-autocomplete or v-combobox?

Comment: Just had a look at the source code and couldn't find something like this. You could only keep a copy of the value before the change happens and, on change, compare both versions.
Perhaps also request it as a new feature in their issue tracker?

Answer (score 3):

To know what changed, you have to declare a `v-model`. This v-model is reactive and thus you can watch for the changes on the same.

Since your auto-complete is multiple , declare the `v-model` to be of type `array`.

```
     new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       data () {
         return {
           states: [
            'Alabama',
            'Alaska',
            'American Samoa',
            'Arizona'
           ],
          selected:['Alabama', 'Alaska'] // this is your v-model. and you watch any change to this.
        }
      },
       watch: {
       selected (newSelectedArray, oldSelectedArray) {
         console.log(newSelectedArray);
         console.log(oldSelectedArray);
         // so now comparing your old to new array you would know if a state got 
         // added or removed, and fire subsequent methods accordingly.
       }
   })
      <v-autocomplete
        :items="states"
        v-model="selected"
        item-text="name"
        label="State"
        @change="pushOrRemoveStates()"
```

Here is a code pen for reference: https://codepen.io/jayas/pen/gBVgvx

Answer (score 2):

Try to watch the model of autocomplete.

```
watch:{
 model(val,oldval) {
           //watch you code here
 }
}
//link model as v-model
<v-autocomplete
    v-model="model"
 >
```